# How to use dlib library in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dlib

Is there anyway I can use dlib c++ library in C#. What I understood is creating a dll which can be called from c# may work but I dont know how to do it. Any help is appreciated. I am not familiar with C# and dll. Thank you

Comment: [PInvoke.NET](http://pinvoke.net/) <- How you do this

Comment: This is not really related to dlib, but could be generalized how to call any c++ library in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section on MSDN explains interop: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx